# is there a PAM module for DNSBL lookups?

Tags: security, pam, ids, rbl

I have been enumerating the remaining security concerns on one of my back-end production servers, when I came to the realization that something which could be incredibly useful was missing from my operating systems upstream repository.

I have been looking for a *PAM Module*, which checks the Remote Host IP address against a **DNS Block List** (***DNSBL***).

My use case is that... While *IDS Software* can respond after detecting an  *probe, vulnerability scan, or brute force attack*-

some services `(i.e. Apache2, proFTPd, Sendmail, SpamAssassin)` include a **DNSBL** module or feature, which help vastly decrease the number of machines that can participate in an attack. it does this by blocking known infected or zombie machines, public proxies, and TOR exit relay nodes (for example).

Others, to my knowledge, do not. `Dovecot/Saslauthd` do not include such functionality. These are frequently targeted in *brute force attacks* on my network. these service are still covered by the IDS system, *but suffer a large majority of the attacks*.

*With a PAM Module that checks the remote host IP, during authentication, against a DNSBL... effectively **ALL** services could have this extra layer of resilience against a distributed brute force attack, or probe (limiting the possible machines that can be used in said attack)*

**I am wondering if there is an existing PAM Module to serve this purpose? and if not, why has this been overlooked by developers?**

It would be an incredibly simple module, which (in my opinion) could serve a great purpose..

> For now, I have wrote a script which interfaces with PAM (via the
>   "pam_exec.so" module). For some reason, this is not working (simply
>   causes BASH to crash). When I get the chance, I plan to try the
>   "pam_script.so" module instead..
>
> I would be willing to write a PAM Module to do this, but am not
>   sure how hard it is to get a piece of software into the Debian or
>   Ubuntu Repositories.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a module. Your second question (why) is going to solicit answers that are primarily opinion based, as I cannot think of any definitive reasons for why such a PAM module *couldn't* exist.

Below are the design considerations I identified when assessing feasibility:

- **Speed**: Must *not* stall logins to heck and back. [ssh+PAM are already in in a bad place](https://serverfault.com/a/496666/152073) when it comes to DNS delays under default configs. I'd go as far as to say the DNS lookups to each server should be made in parallel, to avoid stacking timeouts on top of each other.
- **Retries Are Bad**: Using the C library for DNS lookups is fine so long as retries are considered to be under the purview of `/etc/resolv.conf`. If DNS retries are implemented, the module *must not* use the C library for DNS lookups. The end result would be nested retry operations.
- **Skip Private IP Ranges**: RFC1918 (and similar) space should always get a free pass, as it's useless to pass this information to a DNSBL.
- **Lockout Considerations**: What happens when all DNS is unavailable? Does the module always fail the login, barring a private IP? This must be documented.
- **Generate log errors if you're called in the `auth` stack.** The `auth` stack is used for authentication. This module is not used to authenticate. Decisions that bypass the `auth` stack (SSH key auth, GSSAPI auth, etc.) will defeat the module if the user places it there.

Comment: These are all very important aspects to think about when developing such a module. thank you for your opinion, and taking the time to provide potentially very helpful considerations.

Comment: see my comment about a tcp-wrappers *like* implementation of a hosts.allow/deny file, per user. Users could turn on the module for only *specific* services, only specific hosts, or both. using `/etc/skel` It could drop in a default configuration of `DNSBL:ALL:ALLOW` and the user could modify this to white-list their local networks, hostname, etc. furthermore, it could be reasonable that it might used as a drop in replacement for the hosts.allow file, but per user. all-though.. with this functionality and scope, it would be more of a per user TCP-Wrappers replacement module, with DNSBL Support.

Comment: @RapidWebs The services the module should apply to is more a function of the PAM config. An admin who wants this config to apply to `sshd` wouldn't put this module in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, for example. Excluding specific networks is borderline: `pam_access.so` is usually used to skip over a module that you don't want applying to specific network sources.

Comment: (also I'm a terrible person for saying `common-auth` instead of `common-account`)

Comment: I am testing the script based implementation of this module at the moment. and I agree that it should be defined per service using PAM Config. but since the one obvious issue about DNSBL support that we can all agree on.. is that, say , on a shared server.. it needs a way to be be activated or subverted at the users discretion. per host. i realize my idea in the above comment is entirely out of the scope of DNSBL support in PAM, but some sort of user whitelist would need to be implemented.. considering a regular user cannot access /etc/security or /etc/pam.d/ (nor should they be able to..)

Answer (score 1):

I am more of a redhat guy myself but I've long wondered about a similar module. Good question. I haven't seen a module to handle this.

As far as publishing software goes this may help.

I never had good luck with the main repositories but rpmforge (now repoforge ) has some pretty easy going ways to get involved. [See here.](http://repoforge.org/package/)

For debian / ubuntu I havent seen a single large third party repository. They all seem to be product specific. My stuff never seemed to quite fit , and I couldn't ever justifying running my own public facing repository.

I tended to just leave anything that needed to packaged for debian derivatives sitting source on github.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this without much trouble, but it's a bad idea to do so.

First, let's remember what PAM is: it's a system for *handling user logins*. Authentication, authorization, accounting, etc.

So, where this proposal falls down is:

1. It will **slow down legitimate logins**. Typically the slowdown will be imperceptible, as DNS lookups don't take that much time, but they *can* take several seconds or just time out completely. What do you do when that happens? Do you refuse a legitimate user?
2. More importantly, **it will *completely block* legitimate logins, even when everything is working perfectly**. Many users have the misfortune to be on dynamic IP addresses, and they may themselves be on a malware-riddled computer which is participating in a botnet, causing the IP address to be listed in a DNSBL, or have recently been assigned an IP address which is DNSBL listed even though they themselves are clean.

There are plenty of ways to deal with brute-force attacks on various services, the most commonly used of which is fail2ban, but this proposal seems like a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: #2 is very context specific. If the ssh users are customers, then that's a problem. If they're not, there should probably be a firewall involved. If for some reason you *can't* involve a firewall, that's the sweet spot.

Comment: @AndrewB Even I occasionally need to log in to my own servers from arbitrary locations. Since they are all geographically scattered, I could do a VPN between them all, but it doesn't provide that much real benefit. Looks good on the resume though...

Comment: I have one or two services which are being constantly bruteforced. the services are getting connections from a fairly large botnet. i've already had to increase the maximum size of the worker pool, to allow for more incoming connections, in order to process legitimate requests. if i ONLY use very specific DNSBL's, targetting only zombie networks, TOR exit relays, and open proxies. and i cache these requests against a local DNS server. I don't see where the downfall would be. I have also implemented a TCPWrappers *like* system, where you can SKIP the DNSBL check depending on the service or host

Comment: I only came to this opinion because A) as for latency, comparing to the Apache implementation, when caching locally.. it has not added very much additional overhead. the user could set an option for what to do in the event of a DNS timeout, or failed connection.   moreover, like I said, B) they can white-list their local networks, or login using VPN. mail services might be a problem, and for this, they can disable the DNSBL check in their per user configuration. this would resemble a hosts.deny/allowed file, and can disable the check depending on the Service, or Host (or both)(DNSBL:ALL:ALLOW)